# ASP CDONTS FORM

Tags: asp-classic, cdonts

I have a ASP classic form and im using CDONTS email object, How would I include so when users sign up the form they will get an confirmation, I could use the CC but this would CC the email to me so I want it to be different.

Thanks

Comment: You have got .To .CC and .BCC and you can specify different email addresses for each of them as recipients.

Comment: cc and bcc will send the same email to the user, confirmation email is different. I figured it out myself.